# How to open kdiff3 on a specific monitor using Windows

Tags: kdiff3

I'm using kdiff3 0.9.98 64-bit on Windows 11. I have configured kdiff3 as the git merge and diff tool, and very much enjoy using it.

Is there a way I can set the default window position for kdiff3 so that it always opens on my second (of three) monitor?

I've scanned the online help and configuration settings but couldn't find anything appropriate.